# Forward HLS Stream - Solution needed

Tags: nginx, ffmpeg, wowza, http-live-streaming, ffserver

i'm receiving a HLS/AppleHTTP stream with FFmpeg. The source stream looks like:

```
Input #0, hls,applehttp, from 'http://example.com/hls/index.m3u8':
   Duration: 00:00:00.09, start: 42870.540944, bitrate: 91 kb/s
   Program 0
   Metadata:
      variant_bitrate : 0
   Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p, 1024x576 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 12.50 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc
   Stream #0:1: Audio: aac ([15][0][0][0] / 0x000F), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 114 kb/s
   Stream #0:2: Unknown: none ([21][0][0][0] / 0x0015)
```

I need to forward this kind of stream with FFmpeg to a Stream Server. My problem is, how to do it with FFmpeg without encoding and have high CPU usage (i think -video copy -audio copy). Second, which Streaming Server Software is the best (low cpu usage) to recieve the stream and send it to the users as HLS stream?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**HLS** stands for **HTTP Live Streaming**. You don't need a special server to send it to the clients, just a regular web server like Nginx (one of your tags).

You can do:

`ffmpeg -i http://example.com/hls/index.m3u8 -c copy /path/to/web/dir/index.m3u8`

The command will create the playlist and copy the segments to `/path/to/web/dir` which is located in the web server's document root. The clients only need the new URL.

Things will get more complicated if the input playlist is a master playlist containing multiple variant streams. In this case you need to capture all individual streams to different directories and write a new master playlist on your side to regroup the different streams.

Comment: thank you very much for this great solution! i didn't know that ffmpeg will continualy "download" the segments and create a index.m3u8 file. This is really cool. Thanks again.

Comment: i just have tested your solution, the idea ist great, but... when i play it with VLC, the segments change is every 2 seconds... i have already added the option -segment_time 30 but its no change... here my whole ffmepg command: ./ffmpeg -i h**p://example.com/hls/index_2500.m3u8 -c copy -hls_wrap 18 -hls_list_size 9 -segment_list_flags +live -segment_time 30 /var/www/hls/index.m3u8 ...and the stream is like freezing on every file change... do you know how to solve it? btw. i'm using lighty instead of nginx.. could be this te problem?

Comment: Solved. have added -hls_time `./ffmpeg -i http://example.com/index.m3u8 -c copy -segment_list_flags +live -hls_time 10 -hls_list_size 6 -hls_wrap 10 -segment_list_type m3u8 -map 0:0 -map 0:1 -segment_time 10 /var/www/hls/index.m3u8` Thanks for support.

Comment: Yes, 2s is the default if you don't specify anything.

Comment: `-c copy` throws an error for me: `At least one output file must be specified my.m3u8 command not found`

Answer (score 0):

Better worked with me, changed hls_wrap to be equal to hls_list_size, also hsl_time equals to segment_time

```
./ffmpeg -i http://example.com/index.m3u8 -c copy -segment_list_flags +live -hls_time 4 -hls_list_size 6 -hls_wrap 6 -segment_list_type m3u8 -map 0:0 -map 0:1 -segment_time 4 /var/www/hls/index.m3u8
```